# How to implement dialog pick-an-option in Android MVVM Architecture

Tags: java, android, mvvm

i'm trying to get into MVVM pattern and my problem is that I'm not really sure if I use it correctly. View is responsible for all UI operations (like show stuff?) but what happens when we need to change something in the logic.

So what I really wanna do is, show a dialog with certain options, pick one and reload the app.

I have implement the functions in MainActivity class and i use mCountrySelection.show() when action needed.

```
    public void createCountriesDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Available Countries");

        GridView gridView = new GridView(MainActivity.this);
        final String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
        final String[] codes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.codes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
        gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dialogBuilder.setView(gridView);
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mCountrySelection = dialogBuilder.create();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                PreferencesManager.setCountry(countries[position], codes[position]);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(PreferencesManager.getCountry());

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.a_main_frame, new ArticlesFragment(), "ArticlesFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                mCountrySelection.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAboutDialog()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder aboutBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        aboutBuilder.setTitle("Top News v1.0");
        aboutBuilder.setMessage("Simple application for displaying Top Headlines from newsapi.org.\n\nIcons made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com.");
        aboutBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mAbout = aboutBuilder.create();
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe the scenario step by step? for example when you show the dialog? what data are dynamic and should be provided by business logic?

Comment: Well, i show them in OnOptionsItemSelected using mCountrySelection.show();

The logic is to save using shared prefeferences the country code which is used in retrieving headlines from

Answer (score 0):

Make 1 interface **ItemClick** and implement this interface from where you are calling Dialog.

```
public interface ItemClick{
public void onClick(int position, String country);
}
```

Pass this interface reference to your dialog method

```
public void createCountriesDialog(ItemClick listner)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Available Countries");

        GridView gridView = new GridView(MainActivity.this);
        final String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
        final String[] codes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.codes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
        gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dialogBuilder.setView(gridView);
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                listener = null;
            }
        });

        mCountrySelection = dialogBuilder.create();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            { 
                listener.onclick(position, countries[position]);
                PreferencesManager.setCountry(countries[position], codes[position]);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(PreferencesManager.getCountry());

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.a_main_frame, new ArticlesFragment(), "ArticlesFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

                mCountrySelection.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Then when you click on grid item, using interface reference call **onclick** method 
Now when you will receive a callback in **onClick**(int pos , String country)

Using your view model make api call and reload screen.

Set listener =null when dialog dismiss to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Bussiness logic is supposed to happen in ViewModels, but, we shouldn't use View references on ViewModels as well.

Comment: Yes., All business logic should be in Viewmodel.  I haven't passed any view reference to viewmodel.

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't get you, i have createCountriesDialog function in MainActivity, why should I use onclick listener?

Answer (score 0):

1- Expose a mutable `LiveData` or `Observer` in your `ViewModel`

```
public MutableLiveData<Pair<String, String>> countryInfo = new MutableLiveData<>()
```

2- Pass the user selection to the `ViewModel`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
   viewModel.countryInfo.setValue(new Pair(countries[position], codes[position]))
   mCountrySelection.dismiss();
}
```

3- Run your use-case (business logic) in your `ViewModel` (uploading info to server, saving it in database, etc.)

4- Update `View` through exposing another `Observable` (in this case the same `countryInfo` will work)
In MainActivity observe the `countryInfo`:

```
viewmodel.countryInfo.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
      // Update the UI
      PreferencesManager.setCountry(countries[position], codes[position]);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(PreferencesManager.getCountry());

      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         .replace(R.id.a_main_frame, new ArticlesFragment(), "ArticlesFragment");
         .commit();
   }
});
```

P.S: It is considered best if you move this line to *ViewModel* as it is contain part of business logic:

```
PreferencesManager.setCountry(countries[position], codes[position]);
```

Comment: What if I keep the hole thing, and just move the setCountry in ViewModel? Is it consider wrong practice of MVVM?

Comment: Of course it all depends on your business logic, by isolating the logic from view you can achieve a clean code which later can be refactored easily. For start just refactor the code however you deem appropriate as you are the one knowing the business logic the best.

Comment: @Raf Did it work for you? I would like to know how you handled the dialog ^^

Comment: Well, i moved it on my fragment, kept the UI logic into it and moved business logic into my ViewModel.

https://github.com/h01d/Top-News-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/h01d/newsapp/ui/article/ArticlesFragment.java

Comment: @Raf thanks for sharing the code, here is few insight: 1) try replacing articles observable with flowable, this way you can always get latest changes in your view. 2) move reloadData logic to viewModel, after all it is a business logic that data should be reloaded after country selected. finally I would be happy to contribute, is it ok or it's your playground?

Comment: i'm glad you liked it and thank you for your suggestions, how can I contact you for further questions about it? Project is just something for demonstrating MVVM pattern and nothing more, contribution is not really necessary.